# Finding the correct directory on target for MSBUILD removedir

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

Finding the correct directory on target for MSBUILD

Hello,

I am trying to remotely clear out an “imagecache” folder on my website in my .pubxml file after I do my build.  The problem is, when I do so when running my publish to the remote server via Web Deploy I get the following error back:

**Directory "App_Data/images/imagecache/w-400" doesn't exist. Skipping.**

This is my current build script:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>mysite.com</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>NotRealServer</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>mysite.com</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>UserNameHere</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <RemoveDir Directories="App_Data/images/imagecache/w-400"/>
</Target>
```

I have also tried the following to no avail.  I am not sure how I can give MSBuild the directory on my remote web server I need to delete.

```
<RemoveDir Directories="$( DeployIisAppPath)/App_Data/images/imagecache/w-400"/>
```

And

```
<RemoveDir Directories="/App_Data/images/imagecache/w-400"/>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how your web publish is configured.

If you are publishing to a file share, then use a UNC path.  If you are publishing to an FTP, then MSBuild isn't going to have a way to access that folder.

Here is an example of a RemoveDir task on a UNC share.

`<RemoveDir Directories="\\Server\Share\folder" Condition="Exists('\\Server\Share\folder')" ContinueOnError="WarnAndContinue"/>`

The *Condition* and *ContinueOnError* attributes I have entered above aren't required, but they are a good idea.  The way this task is configured the RemoveDir will be skipped if the folder doesn't exist and if it does exist and and there is an error, the task will issue a warning and the build process will continue.